# Use /usr/bin/python3 in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I run `jupyter-notebook /path/to/a/jupyter/notebook.ipynb`, the Jupyter notebook appears to be running using the python executable at `/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python`, as commands such as `import matplotlib` do not raise an error, whereas the command `import dolfin` raises a `ModuleNotFoundError` (this module was not installed using conda). After an interactive python module is started by typing `/usr/bin/python3` in the terminal, the command `import dolfin` does not raise an error, as this module was installed in such a way that it can be imported from the `/usr/bin/python3` executable.

How can I run my Jupyter notebook in such a way that `/usr/bin/python3` will be used instead?

Comment: I recommend you not to use both python and anaconda together, just for avoiding some of those errors. If you configure the Jupyter to run with `/usr/bin/python3` then you will 'lose' all the packages that comes with Anaconda. And they are already installed in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
path/to/your/python3 -m jupyter-notebook /path/to/a/jupyter/notebook.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if using `/usr/bin/python3` may not be a good idea, here is a workaround that appears to work as described in the question.

Inside `/home/myusername/.bashrc` there is the following block of code:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# commenting following lines makes the notebook use /usr/bin/python3
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!

__conda_setup="$('/home/loic/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/loic/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/loic/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/loic/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

After commenting this block of code, opening a notebook in a new terminal and running `import sys`, `print(sys.executable)` prints `/usr/bin/python3`.